# Compare Four Columns with two column return?

Tags: excel, vba

I been having an issue. What I'm trying to accomplish is compare four columns, if the cells match then return two cells in the same row.
[image: explaination]
For an example I'm comparing both A&B to D&E with an output of F&G on the same row. The destination doesn't matter much as I can change it.
What I have done only compares two columns, which works, but it also adds other cells that shouldn't apply to that particular line.

```
Sub Add_XY()
For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Columns("K").Cells
Dim offs As Long: offs = 2 ' <-- Initial offset, will increase after each match
compareValue = cell.Value & "-" & cell.Offset(, 1).Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("K6").Value = compareValue
If Not compareValue = "-" Then

For Each compareCell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("P&T Data").UsedRange.Columns("AI").Cells
'For Each compareCell In   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells

  If compareCell.Value & "-" & compareCell.Offset(, 1).Value = compareValue Then

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("K6").Value = compareCell.Value & "-" & compareCell.Offset(, 1).Value 'test return value
    cell.Offset(, offs).Value = compareCell.Offset(, 5).Value
    cell.Offset(, offs + 1).Value = compareCell.Offset(, 6).Value
    offs = offs + 4 ' <-- now shift the destination column by 4 for next match
    Else
    End If

Next compareCell

End If

Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: So can you give an example in the above dataset, of what WOULD be considered a match?  (Row 2,3, 4 or 5 ?) And what would the result need to be in Column F and G?

Comment: there are two matches, peanut butter (A2:B2) and french fry (A4:B4). The result would be the next two columns (F:G) in the same row displayed in columns I and J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with the data entered exactly as shown in your picture.

```
Sub Test()

For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells

    compareValue = cell.Value & "-" & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value

    If Not compareValue = "-" Then

    For Each compareCell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells

        If compareCell.Offset(0, 3).Value & "-" & compareCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = compareValue Then

        cell.Offset(0, 8) = cell.Offset(0, 5)
        cell.Offset(0, 9) = cell.Offset(0, 6)
        Else
        End If

    Next compareCell

    End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the code and I can't get it to work. If I test it and set a cell to equal compareCell if the statement is satisfied it returns "-". I updated my question to include what I have done.

Comment: I found out why it wasn't working. There was leading spaces in one column. Trimmed and all set. Thanks!